# Authenticated Connector using import.io with extra screen not working

Tags: import.io

I am trying to create an authenticated login to a website using import.io but before I get to the username and password screen I have to enter an ID number in another screen. I have recorded all the actions, but when I stop recording I get "You did not enter just a username and password" and wont let me go any further.
If I enter the ID number and navigate to the username and password screen THEN start recording, import.io rather unhelpfully reloads the page, which takes me back to the ID number screen.

How do I get import.io to accept the ID, username and password as logon credentials OR how do I stop import.io from reloading the page when I hit record?

Comment: Does entering the ID generate a POST or GET? If its a GET just use the URL it directs you to, if its POST see if you can re-create the post with your ownscript then just point ImportIO at your own script.

Comment: Can you share what is the website?